# Minimum EigenValue

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization

From Rayleigh Equation, we know for symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A$
$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}}\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} = \lambda_{\min}(A)$$

My question is does the same equation hold for the following scenario
$$\inf_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\setminus\{x^*\}}\frac{(x-x^*)^TA(x-x^*)}{(x-x^*)^T(x-x^*)} = \lambda_{\min}(A)$$

where $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $n$ dimensions and $x^*$ is a fixed element in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Further, it seems that the minimum can be achieved if $x^*$ is orthogonal to the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigen value. Can this also be proved formally/

Comment: in addition to divide by zero issues: have you tried working this out with $2\times 2$ examples where $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: I need another restriction that $x \neq x^*$. But with this it seems like with a change in variables it could be reduced to the first equation. And thus would hold true

Comment: again $2\times 2$ examples you can attempt:  I suggest $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $x^*$ selected as the first standard basis vector.

Comment: In that case the answer would be 0 right the minimum eigenvalue. Essentially just minimize $(x-1)^2$ where $x$ is between $[-1,1]$

Comment: I am sorry but do you have an answer

Comment: As pointed out in a comment above, there is a division by zero issue. The Rayleigh-ish quotient is undefined when $x=x^\ast$. So, you should remove $x^\ast$ from the domain $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. You should also replace minimum by infimum, because the minimum may not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few nice ways to do this but I focus on the technique of **(1) make the minimum eigenvalue 0**, i.e. all associated eigenvectors for the minimum eigenvalue $\in \ker A$.  Note this implies $A\succeq \mathbf 0$.

We do this by translation: considering $A_\gamma := A + \gamma I$ for $\gamma := -\lambda_\min$
$\dfrac{\mathbf x^T A_\gamma \mathbf x}{\mathbf x^T\mathbf x} = \dfrac{\mathbf x^T A \mathbf x}{\mathbf x^T\mathbf x}+\gamma$
which is precisely the amount that all eigenvalues shift by in $A\mapsto A_\gamma$.
And the same preservation occurs when we consider
$\dfrac{\big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)^T A_\gamma \big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)}{\big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)^T  \big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)}=\dfrac{\big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)^T A\big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)}{\big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)^T  \big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)} + \gamma$ for any $\mathbf x \neq \mathbf x^*$

So we can assume WLOG (1) is true.

**To verify the lower bound:**
for any $\mathbf x \neq \mathbf x^*$ we have
$\big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)^T A \big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)\cdot  \big \Vert\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big \Vert_2^{-2} \cdot\geq   0$
because $A$ is PSD

**To show that the bound is tight**
$W:=\ker\big( A\big)$ and split into two cases

**(i)**  $\mathbf x^*\notin W^\perp$ (infimum is attained)
then $\mathbf x^* = \alpha' \mathbf w + \beta'\mathbf v$ for some unit length vectors $\mathbf w \in W$ and $\mathbf v\in W^\perp$  where $\alpha'\neq 0$  and of course $(\alpha')^2 + (\beta')^2 =1$
Then $\mathbf x:= -\alpha' \mathbf w + \beta'\mathbf v$ meets the lower bound with equality since $\mathbf 0 \neq \mathbf x - \mathbf x^* = -2\alpha'\cdot \mathbf w \in \ker A$

**(ii)** $\mathbf x^*\in W^\perp$  (infimum not attained)
for some $\mathbf w \in W$ with length 1
in this case write $\mathbf x \in \mathbb S^{n-1}-\big\{\mathbf x^*\big\}$  as

$\mathbf x = \alpha \mathbf w + \beta\mathbf x^*$  where $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 =1 $ and note $(\mathbf x^*)^TA\mathbf x^* =\eta \in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}$

consider this sequentially using $\mathbf x_k$ with $\beta_k:=1-\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^k=\frac{2^k-1}{2^k} $ which implies $\alpha_k^2 = \frac{2^{k+1}-1}{4^k}$
$\big(\mathbf x_k - \mathbf x^*\big) = \big(\alpha_k \mathbf w + (\beta_k-1) \mathbf x^*\big)\implies \big(\mathbf x_k - \mathbf x^*\big)^T A \big(\mathbf x_k - \mathbf x^*\big) = \eta (1-\beta_k)^2$  and
$\big \Vert\mathbf x_k - \mathbf x^*\big \Vert_2^{-2} = \Big(\alpha_k^2 +\big(1-\beta_k\big)^2\Big)^{-1} $ and  we have

$\implies \big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)^T A \big(\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big)\cdot  \big \Vert\mathbf x - \mathbf x^*\big \Vert_2^{-2} = \eta  \cdot  \dfrac{(1-\beta_k)^2}{\alpha_k^2 +\big(1-\beta_k\big)^2}= \eta  \cdot  \dfrac{\frac{1}{4^k}}{\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{4^k} +\frac{1}{4^k}}$
$= \eta  \cdot  \dfrac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}\lt \eta  \cdot  \dfrac{1}{2^{k}}$

which has modulus $\lt \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ by selecting $k$ large enough.  This shows that the lower bound is in fact the infimum.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof of $m_r=\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}}\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} =\inf_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \setminus\{x^*\}}\frac{(x-x^*)^TA(x-x^*)}{(x-x^*)^T(x-x^*)} = m_s$**

As $\mathbb S^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, we have

$$m_r=\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}}\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} \le \inf_{x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \setminus\{x^*\}}\frac{(x-x^*)^TA(x-x^*)}{(x-x^*)^T(x-x^*)} = m_s$$

Now for any $y \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$, we have

$$\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty} = \frac{y_1^TAy_1}{y_1^Ty_1}$$ where $y_1 = \frac{y}{\Vert y \Vert}$. So we can suppose that $\Vert y \Vert = 1$. If $y$ is not orthogonal to $x^*$, we can write

$$\lambda y=x-x^*$$ where $-x$ is the symmetric of $x^*$ with regard to the line generated by $y$ and  $\lambda $ a scalar. In that case, we get
$$y^TAy=\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}= \frac{(\lambda x)^TA(\lambda x)}{(\lambda x)^T(\lambda x)} = \frac{(x-x^*)^TA(x-x^*)}{(x-x^*)^T(x-x^*)} \ge m_s .$$

If $y \perp x^*$, we can find a sequence $\{y_n\}$ of $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ converging to $y$ such that $y_n$ is not perpendicular to $x^*$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. According to what has just been proven, we have for all $n \in \mathbb N$

$$y_n^TAy_n=\frac{y_n^TAy_n}{y_n^Ty_n} \ge m_s.$$ And as the map $z \to z^TAz$ is continuous, we also get that
$$y^TAy=\frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty} \ge m_s.$$

*This concludes the proof that $m_r=m_s$*.

**Is the minimum attained?**

The minimum may not be attained if $x^*$ is orthogonal to the eigenvector of the minimum eigenvalue. Take

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, x^*=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $$ for $x =\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta\\
\sin \theta
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb S\setminus \{x^*\}$ the numerator of $$\frac{(x-x^*)^TA(x-x^*)}{(x-x^*)^T(x-x^*)}$$ will never vanish while the minimum eigenvalue is zero.

Comment: I read OP's statement as *false*.  The issue comes down to the meaning of $x^*$ being a 'fixed element'.  If it is in fact fixed before we see arbitrary conforming $A$ then the statement cannot be true by triangle inequality. The reason I gave multiple prompts to OP to work on the $2\times 2$ examples was to flush this out.

Comment: @user8675309 If you think that there is an error in my proof, just say where it is.

Comment: I somehow feel the solution is correct. But I am still not accepting it because waiting for @user8675309 to come up with a counter example

Comment: @rostader No issue with that approach. However, if you’re convinced with the proof… you may be waiting for long!

Comment: This answer isn't complete. Consider the case of the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$. Let $x^\ast$ be the south pole. The issue is that if an eigenvector $y$ corresponding to $\lambda_\min(A)$ happens to sit on the horizontal plane, it cannot be realised by any scalar multiple of $x-x^\ast$, because $x-x^\ast$ always lie inside the open upper half space. One may show that the modified Rayleigh quotient converges to $\lambda_\min(A)$ for some sequence $\{x_n\}\to x^\ast$, but this is not shown in your answer.

Comment: So if I am not mistaken the issue is more along lines of using infimum rather than minimum

Comment: @rostader Absolutely. Everything is right if you change $\min$ with $\inf$. Which is by the way the usual way to define the norm of an operator. I’ll update my answer using $\inf$. Where you using $\min$ in your question having really in mind that the $\inf$ should be attained?

Comment: Another thing I seem to notice from the geometry is that as long as $x^*$  does not remain perpendicular to minmum eigenvector of $A$ the minimum can be achieved

Comment: Thank you @user1551.  I had thought I led OP (and mathcounterexamples) to this either with my $2\times 2$ example or the fact that $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ with a point deleted is not compact (usual topology in $\mathbb R^n$) so why people would conflate $\inf$ and $\min$ I don't know.

Comment: @rostader your comment is correct about orthogonality but you've accepted an as answer a proof that still is wrong. It says  **"Now for any $y \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$, we have**  $\lambda y=x-x^*$" and the final line of the post has $y$ in the denominator so $\lambda \neq 0$.  This assertion isn't true.  E.g. suppose $x^* \perp y$ then re-arranging terms  $-x = (-\lambda)y -x^*$  and $1=\big \Vert -x\big \Vert_2^2=\big\Vert(-\lambda)y -x^*\big \Vert_2^2 = \lambda^2 + 1 \gt 1$ which is a contradiction.  My first comment called this triangle inequality but really it's parallelogram law.

Comment: @user8675309 This is a good catch!

Comment: note: for a clean finish, my preceding comment should say $x^*$ and $y$ are orthonormal

Comment: So I guess if we give an additional statement that $x^*$ is not perpendicular to the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue then not only is the infimum at the minimum eigenvalue but it is also achieved

Comment: @user8675309 why don't you give a detailed answer instead of writing in comments

Comment: @rostader -- you've already accepted an answer that is (i) inaccurate and (ii) doesn't match your original post that still references a minimum not an infiimum.  I am not seeing an adequate amount of diligence on your end for me to do a proper answer.

Comment: @user8675309 I have edited the question and have also added the extra point about the orthogonality which for the time seems to be the condition for which the minimum is achieved. Furthermore the answer accepted yesterday have been revoked. So as of now the question still remains unanswered and hopefully is correct

Comment: @rostader I updated my answer following the update of your question.

Comment: Hey thanks for your cointinual effort. Really appreciate it @mathcounterexamples.net

Answer (score 0):

We may use the properties of the usual real-vlaued inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$:
We have that

$$\frac{x^T Ax}{x^Tx}=\frac{\langle x,Ax \rangle}{\langle x,x \rangle}=
\frac{\langle x,Ax \rangle}{\|x\|^2}=\langle \frac{x}{\|x\|},A \frac{x}{\|x\|} \rangle$$

So we actually have that

$$\lambda_{\text{min}}=\min_{\|x\|=1}\langle x,A x \rangle.$$

Now apply the same argument to see that

$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{S}^n\setminus\{x^*\}}
\frac{(x-x^*)^T A (x-x^*)}{(x-x^*)^T A (x-x^*)}=
\min_{y\in \mathbb{S}^n\setminus\{0\}}
\frac{y^T A y}{y^T A y}
=\min_{\|x\|=1}\langle x,A x \rangle$$